# How to Mention Projects and Tools of a Customer in Job Application

Tags: interviewing, resume, ethics

It is clear to me that naming any business partners of the current employer can get me into legal trouble or at least mark me as a big unreliable mouth in a job application or interview.

I would like to apply to an OEM now, which my current employer contracted as a second level supplier. So I have worked full time in a big project of the OEM around a year and a half. I know their technology, tools and how their business run. I have a unique advantage. But how should I state it in my resume and cover letter and in the interview.

Comment: 1) Why do you believe that first para?  2) Are these tools proprietary or well known tools?

Comment: 1.) It is stated in my contract. 2.) Proprietary.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, take a look at your non-disclosure agreement. It might very well be that you are easily allowed to write all of that to the OEM themselves without violating anything. Non-disclosure agreements are signed between your company and the OEM, you are an employee of your company, you're going to talk to an employee of the OEM, so it's very likely that you're covered.

Also, if their technology and tools are publicly available, you can easily write that without violating anything. In theory, you could have studied it at home or during a seminar.